# How to print tree from dictionary in python

Tags: python, linux, dictionary, tree, ldd

I am trying to implement **ldd** kind of application in **python**. However, I am struggling to represent the data as a tree like structure. The linux libraries are dependent on some other libraries, so my task is to track the dependency list until no dependency is found.
I have data in dictionary shown below,

```
{lib_A: [lib_1, lib_2, lib_3, lib_4], lib_1: [lib_x, lib_y, lib_z], lib_x: [lib_i], lib_y: [lib_p], lib_2: [lib_a, lib_b], lib_a: [lib_11]......}
```

where **lib_1**, **lib_2**, **lib_3**, and **lib_4** depends on **lib_A**. Then **lib_x**, **lib_y**, and **lib_z** depends on **lib_1** and so on. The list continues until no dependency is found. If I print the data in a for loop the output looks like this as shown below,

```
for lib, dep_lib in dependency_dict.items():
    print(lib, dep_lib)
```

```
lib_A [lib_1, lib_2, lib_3, lib_4]
lib_1 [lib_x, lib_y, lib_z]
lib_x [lib_i]
lib_y [lib_p]
lib_2 [lib_a, lib_b]
lib_a [lib_11]
...
..
```

and I want to represent the above data as a tree like structure as shown below.

```
lib_A <= lib_1
         <= lib_x
            <= lib_i
         <= lib_y
            <= lib_p
         <= lib_z
      <= lib_2
         <= lib_a
            <= lib_11
         <= lib_b
      <= lib_3
      <= lib_4
```

Comment: How are libraries that nothing depends on represented in your data structure? Are they missing from the dict, or are they present as keys, but with empty strings as values? Can the same library show up in mutliple places in the output?

Comment: @Blckknght Libraries that nothing depends on will not be present as keys. In the above example, there are no libraries that depend on **lib_i**, the tree ends at that point. So it won't be present as keys. Currently, with my implementation, I am avoiding libraries showing up multiple times just to avoid repeating the same loop, but a good implementation should handle duplicates as well, I would like to implement handling of multiple occurrences of the same library in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with a tree based structure, it's often natural to use a recursive function to process it. To produce the output you want, I'd write something like this:

```
def process_lib(data, lib, padding=0):
    if padding == 0:
        print(lib)
    else:
        print(" "*padding, "<=", lib)

    for child in data.get(lib, []): # base case: lib is not in the dict
        process_lib(data, child, padding + 3)  # recursive case
```

This doesn't exactly replicate the first line of your example, since we put `lib_A` on its own line with `lib_1` on the next line. You could put in more special case logic for the `padding == 0` case and figure out how to make the first child directly follow it, but hopefully this output is good enough:

```
lib_A
    <= lib_1
       <= lib_x
          <= lib_i
       <= lib_y
          <= lib_p
       <= lib_z
    <= lib_2
       <= lib_a
          <= lib_11
       <= lib_b
    <= lib_3
    <= lib_4
```

This code probably only works properly for simple trees. If your real data is a more complicated graph with the same libraries showing up at multiple points in the dependency hierarchy, then you need something a little more complicated. You need to keep track of which nodes have already been seen, and either not print them out again at all, or print them but not their dependencies. Here's an implementation that does the latter:

```
def process_lib(data, lib, padding=0, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    if padding == 0:
        print(lib)
    else:
        print(" "*padding, "<=", lib)

    if lib in seen:
        print(" "*(padding+3), "<= ...") # alternate base case
    else:
        seen.add(lib)
        for child in data.get(lib, []):
            process_lib(data, child, padding + 3, seen)
```

If you don't want duplicates at all, use this:

```
def process_lib(data, lib, padding=0, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    if padding == 0:
        print(lib)
    else:
        print(" "*padding, "<=", lib)

    seen.add(lib)
    for child in data.get(lib, []):
        if child not in seen:
            process_lib(data, child, padding + 3, seen)
```

Comment: I tried this code, I think I am almost close to achieving what i intended to. I invoke the function by `process_lib(dependency_dict, lib_A)`, The output looks good but the this goes into infinite loop, the same tree prints like 5 times and get recursion error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. I think if i restrict it to print only once then it should be good.  In the above example, **lib_A** initially prints at row_0 and col_0(which is right), second time it prints  as a child node to **lib_4** and same tree is repeated there onwards.

Comment: I have added an extended question explaining duplicates still exists.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the motivation of the second recursive function you've added to your code. It seems to be flattening dependencies that are not at the top level? That doesn't seem all that useful to me. Does my last implementation, which doesn't allow any duplication, not do what you want in some way? Or can you just explain better what it is that you want, with perhaps a specific example data set (that includes representative patterns of duplication) and the desired output?